# The title text box is empty on a particular question when I try to edit it

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, title

I am trying to edit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22810848/cannot-open-the-urls-on-the-page-using-selenium-webdriver-and-java) and I notice that the title is immediately empty in the edit screen. I just see the placeholder ("What's your programming question? Be specific."), which is unexpected, since the question does have a title.

I've edited questions in the last five minutes or so where this did not occur, and the behaviour does not occur on [this random question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023327/what-would-cause-this-xml-to-use-up-memory), so it looks like it is question-specific. Does the title maybe have a newline or other control character in the database?

I am on Firefox 43.0.4 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Also happening (just on that question for me) on mobile safari but not on the iOS app.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You found a really weird bug but not really a bug, [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) thing. It appears that the first version of the question was removed due to security reasons, the user included their password, so the initial version with the title was deleted making the title not available when you edited it.

Before anyone calls shenanigans, this no longer happens if a user accidentally posts sensitive details. We now have the ability to redact the history of a post, essentially making so these details never existed.  It's a bit safer than just removing a version from the database.

Comment: Ah no problem; so if I edit I guess I should just replace the title with the old version, and it will be OK for future edits from that point on?

Comment: @halfer I've already edited the title into the post so if you attempt to edit it, it will be ok.

Comment: Great, thanks for digging into it!

Comment: "A bit safer" ... a bit more conspiratorial ;) ;)

Comment: Everyone loves a good conspiracy @LightnessRacesinOrbit.